# How to convert types when uploading data with Python API

Tags: python, dolphindb

When I upload data to DolphinDB table with Python API, the `trade_date` column in `dataframe` is a STRING. Now I want to convert this column to DATE type. How can I do this?

I have tried the following script:

```
df['trade_date'] = df["trade_date"].astype('datetime64[D]')
```

However, it is not as expected because it is a NANOTIMESTAMP type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions for your problem.

Solution 1:

Convert data types in DolphinDB:

```
s.upload({'data': data})
s.run('data.replaceColumn!(`timestamp, date(data[timestamp]))')
```

Solution 2:

Specify data type by `__DolphinDB_Type__`.

```
data.__DolphinDB_Type__ = {
  'timestamp': keys.DT_DATE
}
s.upload({'data': data})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `datetime64[ns]` for Dolphindb's `NANOTIMESTAMP`